# PHP upgrade from 5.4 to 5.6 - strange error with simple function

Tags: php

I upgraded a shared GoDaddy server from PHP 5.4 to PHP 5.6 and now I get an error that says 
"Fatal error: Cannot redeclare debug_to_console(). Previously declared in debug_to_console.php"

```php
function debug_to_console( $data ) {
    $output = $data;
    if ( is_array( $output ) )
        $output = implode( ',', $output);

    echo "<script>console.log( 'Debug Objects: " . $output . "' );</script>";
}
```

This function worked fine in 5.4, and searching for breaking changes in 5.6, I do not find any.
If I have this php file included (like below) on other files and then use the function like this:

```
include_once($INC_DIR. 'functions/debug_to_console.php');

//usage
debug_to_console('id= ' . $id);
```

Does the function redeclare each time I reference it in a php file?

Thanks

Comment: did you grep to see how many times that code is repeated?

Comment: No, I will do that.

Comment: Your error message says the function is defined in a file named `debug_to_console.php` but you're showing us code that includes `database.class.php`. You've probably got `include debug_to_console.php` in more than one place, and can likely just change that to include_once.

Comment: And as a side note you really need to get to PHP 7.3 as support for 5.6 ended over 9 months ago.

Comment: @AlexHowansky oops, that was the wrong include line. I changed it. So, "include_once" would declare that function just for the php file it is referenced on?

Comment: @Dave strangely, the particlular Godaddy server account only shows options to select up to 5.6. I will see what the plan is to get a newer version of PHP.

Comment: Yes, just for the file that includes it, but if you've got lots of includes it's easy to accidentally include more than once. So, you'd need to make sure every `include debug_to_console.php` is changed to `include_once debug_to_console.php`, and that you have `function debug_to_console() { ... }` defined *only* in that file.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I will give it a try.